# "Symbol's function definition is void: org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done"

Tags: org-mode, init-file, debugging

I've recently started using Org-mode, and when I last restarted Emacs, I got the error message `Symbol's function definition is void: org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done`. Upon opening Emacs again using `--debug-init`, I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done)
  (org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/daniel/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3069
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/daniel/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/daniel/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/daniel/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@ ;; more stuff after this that wouldn't paste for some reason
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

This is likely referring to the following line in my `init.el` file:

```
(org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
```

If I comment this line out and evaluate it, I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done)
  (org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
  eval((org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t) nil)
  eval-expression((org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t) nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
```

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.2. I have no idea what's happening. Can anybody help?

Comment: Search your user configuration file for `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` and post your configuration that uses that option -- most of the org-mode users here should be able to figure out what is wrong.  You likely just have the wrong format, that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error means that you're trying to call a variable as if it was a function. Use `setq` to change the value of a variable: `(setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)`